# How do I make a circle with particles?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

[image]so I'm fairly new to commands and I'm trying to make a among us med scan with particles but all the tutorials I find are out of date or on bedrock and I wanna know if there's a way to make a particle circle go up and down before disappearing?

If someone could let me know that would be great.

edit: now I just don't know the name of the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [this](https://cloudwolfyt.github.io/pages/gens/particle-plots.html).  That is a particle plotter by [Cloud Wolf on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZnBqVITQ0dloqUU0fGxY3g) that generates a function for Minecraft.  The website has a video on how to use it (link is broken at the time of answer).  To make the circle, in the drop down box choose sphere. Then, change the y value to 0. That will make a flat circle.  To see it in the display press draw.
If you want a flat circle on a different axis change the x or z value to 0 instead.  For the animation you could make frames using schedule to run a separate function that runs the particle function at an entity you use to control position.

If you want to learn how to use the generator [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mi1B0IeVWw) is the link to the video about how to use the generator because as of writing this answer the button in the website doesn't work.  If you have any questions please ask.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Please don't use comments to have long back and forth discussions. If the question needs more information, please edit it in so the answer can be updated. If you have a new question, please ask it separately.

Comment: oh well I'm sorry but you can only post like 2 questions every 2 days and technicly its the same problem